# how to change C3P0 user and password on runtime

Tags: java, c3p0

when I start is, my config was:`user=test1&password=test1`

And I want to changed it to `user=test2&password=test2`

here is the code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/config/spring/appcontext-test.xml" })
public class SingleDataSourceProcessorTest {

    @Autowired
    private ComboPooledDataSource masterDs;

    @Test
    public void test_c3p0_datasource_to_single_datasource()
            throws InterruptedException, SQLException {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        query();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        query();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        Thread.sleep(3000);

         masterDs.setUser("test2");
         System.out.println("change username");
         masterDs.setPassword("test2");
         System.out.println("change password");

        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

    private void query() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = masterDs.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("select @@read_only");
        result.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

my spring config:

```
<bean id="masterDs" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db1" />
    <property name="user" value="test1" />
    <property name="password" value="test1" />
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />
</bean>
```

When the code has changed the `user` only, the other thread use the wrong `user` and `password` pair to query the database and throws exceptions.

So how to change the `user` and `password` on run time?

Comment: have you embedded the original user and password in the jdbc url? (if so, don't do that. it looks like it, from how you've shown the configuration.)

Comment: @SteveWaldman I use the properties.